# EF Query simplification

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

```
var filters = new List<AllowedFilterModel>();
var collections = _collectionManager.GetAll();

var storesLookup = collections.Select(c => new LookupModel
{
    Id = c.StoreId,
    DisplayName = c.StoreName
}).ToList();

var distinctstoresLookup = storesLookup.GroupBy(c => new {c.DisplayName,c.Id }).Select(c=>c.First()).ToList();

filters.Add(new CollectionFilterModel(FilterVariables.Store)
{
    FilterType = FilterDataType.Collection,
    AllowedValues = distinctstoresLookup
});
```

Is there a way to simplify this query or combine some of them?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the current problem? Does `GetAll()` return a not-yet-enumerated `IQueryable`? ... You need to actually describe the problem and the goal, a question that amounts to "please fix this" is not accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can drop the intermediate `ToList` calls. They needlessly materialize the query into a list. It looks like your repository is supposed to query the database. `ToList` forces client-side evaluation and this breaks performance in a big way. Use SQL Server Profiler to see what I mean.

Likely, `_collectionManager.GetAll()` must return an `IQueryable`.

Your `GroupBy` implements just a `Distinct`. Then, from each group you pick the first. But all objects in the same group are identical. I suspect that's a logic error...

As the query stands you could make it into:

```
var results =
 _collectionManager.GetAll()
 .Select(c => new LookupModel
 {
     Id = c.StoreId,
     DisplayName = c.StoreName
 })
 .Distinct()
 .ToList();
```

Which is far more readable than using all those temporary variables.